# FO:NV: Which "pistol-type weapon" perks affect the sawed-off shotgun?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

There are some perks in Fallout: New Vegas that boost performance of one-handed guns, for example:

> [Gunslinger](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gunslinger#Affected_weapons_in_Fallout:_New_Vegas)
>
> "While using a pistol (or **similar one-handed weapon**), your chance to hit in V.A.T.S. is increased by 25% [...]"
>
> [Run 'n Gun](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Run_%27n_Gun)
>
> "The Run 'n Gun perk reduces accuracy penalties with **one-handed ranged weapons** (Guns or Energy Weapons) while walking or running"

The [sawed-off shotgun](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sawed-off_shotgun_(Fallout%3A_New_Vegas)) behaves like a one-handed gun in-game (full movement speed when drawn, holstering on the hip, etc.), so it should qualify as **one-handed weapon similar to a pistol**, but it is not in the list of weapons affected by Gunslinger(the variant from FO3 however is). The Run 'n Gun article isn't very detailed either.

**Question:** Is the sawed-off shotgun exempted from those perks (despite qualifying), or is it missing from the Nukapedia articles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sawed-off shotgun is both a shotgun and one-handed gun. Even though there isn't a Wikia article on one-handed guns you can use the [Jury-Rigging perk page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Jury_Rigging#One-handed_guns) as a reference of one-handed guns. The perks listed above should affect all one-handed guns, which the sawed-off shotgun falls into.

In this case it appears the wikia article is incomplete. The weapon should be included on the list of affected guns.